# Python: Using where statement to set values for new column from 3 label options

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, where-clause

Here is my current code:

```
merged_left_2['WSITemp>AlmTemp?'] = np.where(   
    merged_left_2['surfaceTemperatureFahrenheit'] > merged_left_2['mean_temp'],
   'hrs_avgtemp_ABOVE_30yrnorm', 'hrs_avgtemp_BELOW_30yrnorm')
```

It states that if `'surfaceTemperatureFahrenheit' > 'mean_temp'`, then label new column 'WSITemp>AlmTemp?' as 'hrs_avgtemp_ABOVE_30yrnorm'.  Otherwise label column as 'hrs_avgtemp_BELOW_30yrnorm'.

How can I adjust the above code to label the new column with `hrs_avgtemp_EQUAL_30yrnorm` if the values are exactly equal to each other?

*Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another np.where

```
merged_left_2['WSITemp>AlmTemp?'] = np.where(
    merged_left_2['surfaceTemperatureFahrenheit'] > merged_left_2['mean_temp'],
   'hrs_avgtemp_ABOVE_30yrnorm', np.where(
    merged_left_2['surfaceTemperatureFahrenheit'] = merged_left_2['mean_temp'],
   'hrs_avgtemp_EQUAL_30yrnorm', 'hrs_avgtemp_BELOW_30yrnorm'))
```